# Replacing text in R without changing other words

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I want to replace certain terms without changing other words. 
Here I want to change `sp` for `indet` without changing other words, such as `species`.

`names <- c ('sp', 'sprucei', 'sp', 'species')`

I have tried `gsub` but when I run it the output is not as I wanted

`gsub (' sp', ' indet', names)`

output:

`[1] "indet"      "indetrucei" "indet"      "indetecies"`

and not:

`[1] "indet"      "sptrucei" "indet"      "sptecies"`

Any advice? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
names <- c ('sp', 'sprucei', 'sp', 'species')
gsub('^sp$', 'indet', names)
# [1] "indet"   "sprucei" "indet"   "species"
```

the `^` requires the match to begin at the start of the string and the `$` requires it to end at the end of the string.

If you had other words before/after the `sp`, you could use `\b` to match word boundaries instead

```
names <- c ('sp', 'sprucei', 'apple sp banana', 'species')
gsub('\\bsp\\b', 'indet', names)
# [1] "indet"       "sprucei"       "apple indet banana"     "species"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, given your example, is this:

```
names <- c ('sp', 'sprucei', 'sp', 'species')
names[names=='sp'] <- 'indet'
names
# [1] "indet"   "sprucei" "indet"   "species"
```

Unlike MrFlick's solution, this won't work if there are spaces or words before or after `'sp'`